# yii url rewrite

Tags: php, url, yii

I'm using Yii and I want to change the URL path. At this point I have a URL like this:

```
controller/action/param1/value1/param2/value2
```

and I want it to be like:

```
controller/value1/value2
```

or maybe would be fine too:

```
controller/action/value1/value2
```

How can I accomplish this? I tried many options in the URLManager settings but it either stays exactly the same or I get an error saying `Undefined index: param2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the documentation for [CUrlManager](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CUrlManager/)

Add the following line to the CUrlManager rules array in main.php

```
'/controller_name/<param1:\w+>/<param2:\w+>' => '/controller_name/action_name',
```

eg.

```
'urlManager'=>array(
        'urlFormat'=>'path',
        'showScriptName'=> false,
        'rules'=>array(
            '/controller_name/<param1:\w+>/<param2:\w+>' => '/controller_name/action_name',
            '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
        ),
    ),
```